# Скорость разработки web приложений

Tags: веб-программирование

Привет всем!
Как Вы считаете какая технология на сегодня самая быстрая для разработки web приложений?

Comment: Технология, которой сам владеешь лучше остальных. Вопрос не совсем корректно задан, ибо технологии комбинируются всегда и везде. Серверная часть это одно, скрипты на стороне клиента - другое. И тем не менее, они совершенно могут быть из одних или разных степей технологий. Вот, скажем, что понимается под Web приложением? Разве есть стандарты, которые говорят, что в любой аппликации обязательно должны быть CSS3, AJAX, библиотеки jQuery и пр.? Нет. Каждая технология пригодна там, где она востребована. Нельзя однозначно утверждать, что одно лучше другого.

Comment: Да немного не так задал вопрос, имелось ввиду про северную часть.

Comment: перефразировал еще хуже

Comment: А если так:
Как сделать крупный сайт за 24 часа)))

Comment: 60к+ зелени + куча китайцов

Answer (score 2):

Учитесь, учитесь и еще раз учитесь, вместо того, чтобы искать серебряную пулю. Не нужно искать "самую быструю технологию", "самый простой язык, чтоб на нем даже не надо было программировать" или еще что-нибудь "самое простое/быстрое/легкое/приносящее бабки". Позволю себе процитировать пользователя [@Котик_хочет_кушать](/users/4149/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C):

> У меня создается такое впечатление, что куча народа занята поиском "той самой-самой правильной книги," которую нужно прочитать, чтобы сразу всему научиться.

так вот ни к чему хорошему эта практика вас не приведет

Comment: да ладно, разве многие не проходили через такие попытки найти философский камень? причем это в каком-то смысле правильный способ - "искать", читать больше книг, статей, что бы найти ту "правильную", которую ты поймешь...

Comment: если вы вдруг не поняли, то речь идет о том, что толпы ленивой и неграмотной школоты хотят по щучьему велению (ну или прочитав  одну "ту самую книгу" из 50 страниц) стать гуру программирования, получать миллионы денег и рвать всех и вся на британский флаг. Так вот - так не бывает

Comment: Кстати, смотрел резюме пользователя @Котик_хочет_кушать, очень сильный специалист.

Comment: резюме - это, конечно, замечательно, но о его высокой квалификации еще лучше говорят его ответы на этом форуме

Comment: Мне знакомо то чувство поиска той самой книги.....    
Но я уже давно этим не занимаюсь, хотел узнать мнение людей что   быстрее для разработки серверной части допустим сравнивая:
Python  
PHP  
Java  
Node  
Ruby

Comment: @evgeniy то, что вы спрашиваете в комментарии, значительно отличается от того, что спросили в вопросе. В таком случае лучше уж переформулируйте изначальный вопрос

Comment: все зависит от задачи, если считать по кол-ву строк кода, это будет очень интересная статистика, я про все языки не знаю, но например на питоне и пхп точно надо меньше строк, чем в джаве..

Comment: >если считать по кол-ву строк кода,

это уже какой-то индус-стайл получается